# Visual Studio Code API Google Maps

Tags: api

Saludes existe alguna extension de intellisense para Visual Studio Code, para poder trabajar con la API de google Maps...

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Es un tema interesante el que preguntas. Probablemente te pongan en espera la pregunta. Quizás porque es muy corta y porque no muestra que has intentado usar. Intenta editarla añadiendo algún detalle más si puedes. Aunque tengo que reconocer que si yo tuviese que preguntar eso tampoco tendría mucho más que poner.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes instalar el [paquete de tipos de Google Maps de NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlemaps)

```
npm install --save @types/googlemaps
```

Esto debería traer las definiciones de tipos de Google Maps de modo que VS Code pueda utilizarlos como intellisense

Comment: gracias ... funciono perfectamente..saludes

Answer (score -1):

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://gmapvsdoc.codeplex.com/)

En esta pagina podras encontrar la descarga directa

Comment: No se refiere a Visual Studio sino a [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Comment: Gracias diego lo instale por npm ..